# How we can count the objects in Iterator using wso2esb

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I am getting array list from my front end that i need to insert into a table using Wso2esb and dss i have almost done that functionality using iterator.I need to give response to front end whenever insertion over of that array list. i wish to count the any obejects which is iterating number of times
 my code is like this

```
<iterate continueParent="true"
                        id="QuestionListMobile"
                        expression="//QuestionsList">
                  <target>
                     <sequence>
                        <property name="ttemplateformid"
                                  expression="get-property('ttemplateformid')"
                                  scope="default"
                                  type="STRING"/>
                        <payloadFactory>
                           <format>
                              <p:Insert_ttemplatedetails_Mobile_Op xmlns:p="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
                                 <xs:templateformid xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$1</xs:templateformid>
                                 <xs:formtemplatesectiondetailid xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$2</xs:formtemplatesectiondetailid>
                                 <xs:questionid xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$3</xs:questionid>
                                 <xs:weightage xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">0</xs:weightage>
                                 <xs:rank xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$4</xs:rank>
                                 <xs:score xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$5</xs:score>
                                 <xs:remarks xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$6</xs:remarks>
                                 <xs:feedback xmlns:xs="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">$7</xs:feedback>
                              </p:Insert_ttemplatedetails_Mobile_Op>
                           </format>
                           <args>
                              <arg expression="get-property('ttemplateformid')"/>
                              <arg expression="//sectionQuestionMapId/text()"/>
                              <arg expression="//QuestionId/text()"/>
                              <arg expression="//Rank/text()"/>
                              <arg expression="//answer/text()"/>
                              <arg expression="//remark/text()"/>
                              <arg expression="//Feedback/text()"/>
                           </args>
                        </payloadFactory>
                        <log level="full"/>
                        <send receive="QuestionsInsertion_Seq3">
                           <endpoint>
                              <address uri="http://localhost:9764/services/ttemplatesectiondetail_DataService/"
                                       format="soap11"/>
                           </endpoint>
                        </send>
                        <log level="full"/>
                     </sequence>
                  </target>
               </iterate>
```

i am doing well how can i know above how many arrays i got

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
          name="QuestionsInsertion_Seq3"
          onError="fault">
   <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT"
             value="true"
             scope="axis2"
             type="STRING"/>
   <property xmlns:f="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"
             xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             name="ttemplatedetailid"
             expression="//f:ttemplatedetailid/text()"
             scope="default"
             type="STRING"/>
   <log>
 <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             name="Total"
             expression="count(//QuestionId/text())"
             scope="default"
             type="STRING"/>
      <property xmlns:f="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"
                xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
                name="ttemplatedetailid"
                expression="//f:ttemplatedetailid/text()"/>
   </log>
```

I am loging QuesionId count but i am not getting i am getting as total is 1.0 only 
i need to count in proxy only or in sequence 
thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can not count the iteration..What you are trying now is, you are getting DS response in your receive sequence, and from the response you are trying to read a value. So, check your response, and see what you are getting from endpoint

Comment: thanx for replay. i am using returned key in wso2dss so how can i count that key for every time which is i am retrieving in sequence so may i know how many keys generated.how can i make it as array for response

Comment: i am getting number of responses ttemplatedetails so how can i keep in one property